# Verify IMAP/POP3 connection to Microsoft Exchange Server 5.5

Tags: imap, pop3, thunderbird, exchange

I wanted to fully explore IMAP connections from the command line, if I can connect via Thunderbird, then I should be able to via `telnet`?!

[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189326#appliesto) detail IMAP login as :-

```
LOGIN NTDOMAIN/NTACCOUNT/ALIAS PASSWORD
```

The settings in my Thunderbird are :-

```
<domain>\<username>\<alias>
```

Various sources state slightly different IMAP commands :-

```
LOGIN user@domain.com <password>                                   (1)
LOGIN <Domain_Name>/<Log_On_Name> <Password>                       (2)
LOGIN <LogOnName>@<DomainName>.<Top-Level_Domain_Name> <Password>  (3)
LOGIN DOMAIN/USERNAME/MAILBOX                                      (4)
LOGIN NTDOMAIN/NTACCOUNT/ALIAS PASSWORD                            (5)
```

#### POP attempts :-

```
telnet <servername> pop3
+OK Microsoft Exchange POP3 server version 5.5.2658.25 ready
user <username>
+OK
pass <password>
-ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

user <domain>\<username>
+OK
pass <password>
-ERR There is no such mailbox on this server
```

The later shows that it my account access was authorised.

#### IMAP attempts :-

```
telnet <servername> imap
* OK Microsoft Exchange IMAP4rev1 server version 5.5.2658.25 (<servername>) ready
login <domain>/<username> <password>
login BAD Protocol Error: "Unidentifiable command specified"
login <username>@<domain>.<servername> <password>
login BAD Protocol Error: "Unidentifiable command specified"
login <domain>/<username>/IanVaughan
login BAD Protocol Error: "Unidentifiable command specified"
LOGIN
* BAD Protocol Error: "Tag not found in command"
login
login BAD Protocol Error: "No space following tag in IMAP command"
LOGIN <domain>/<username> <password>
LOGIN BAD Protocol Error: "Unidentifiable command specified"
LOGIN <username>@<domain> <password>
LOGIN BAD Protocol Error: "Unidentifiable command specified"
```

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood IMAP. Every IMAP command has to be preceded with an identification token, so instead of `LOGIN domain/user/mailbox password` the KB article you quoted advises you to use `? LOGIN domain/user/mailbox password` (note the **?** prepended to the LOGIN command - which is the mentioned token).

BTW: you do not necessarily have to use `domain/user/mailbox` - simply using "user" (the Windows NT logon user name) will connect you to that user's mailbox automatically.

Another thing is the authentication mechanism - plain authentication (simply supplying the password in clear) is discouraged due to its insecurity and thus most servers refuse plain authentication and force users to use a [digest auth](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2831.txt) instead if SSL is not used. I do not know if Exchange 5.5 does so by default, though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use `telnet` to verify the email server connection. However, you need to make sure you are issuing valid commands `Unidentifiable command specified`. Also, you need to make sure you specifying the username and password correctly.

When connecting to POP3 service, I am not sure if `username\domain` format will work. I usually use one of the forms:

```
user username
user username@domain
```

If you can login using an email client such as Thunderbird or Outlook, you can simply use a network sniffer like wireshark to check for the correct POP3/IMAP commands.